How to serialize int32 in little-endian order, and deserialize on both little-endian and big-endian architectures?
I serialize the integer anyway in little-endian order
public byte[] Serialize(int value)
{
    return new byte[4]
    {
        (byte)value,
        (byte)(value >> 8),
        (byte)(value >> 16),
        (byte)(value >> 24)
    };
}

Let's take for example the number '2000':
bitwise, it will look like this:
00000000  00000000  00000111  11010000
(byte)value assigns to the first byte 11010000 which is equivalent to '208' byte;
(byte)(value >> 8) shifts a number 8 bits to the right: 00000000 00000000  00000000  00000111 and assigns the first byte: 00000111 which is equivalent to 7;
the rest with zeros;
and result in bytes is: { 208, 7, 0, 0 }, which bitwise looks like 11010000  00000111  00000000  00000000 !
Here is the first thing that confused me. If in little-endian architectures numbers are stored in that order, when we using bitwise operations the number is flipped into a convenient order, which equivalent to big-endian order, right?
Here is the deserialization code from the standard System.BitConverter.ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex):
fixed (byte* ptr = &value[startIndex])
{
    if (startIndex % 4 == 0)
    {
        return *(int*)ptr;
    }

    if (IsLittleEndian)
    {
        return *ptr | (ptr[1] << 8) | (ptr[2] << 16) | (ptr[3] << 24);
    }

    return (*ptr << 24) | (ptr[1] << 16) | (ptr[2] << 8) | ptr[3];
}

if 'startIndex' is aligned on a 4-byte boundary it casts 'ptr' (pointer to integer data) to integer, which will read little-endian integer incorrectly on a big-endian architecture, so i need to make my own method.
    if (IsLittleEndian)
    {
        return *ptr | (ptr[1] << 8) | (ptr[2] << 16) | (ptr[3] << 24);
    }

Same number '2000' as an example, or in bytes { 208, 7, 0, 0 }
return *ptr bitwise returns 00000000 00000000 00000000 11010000 (ptr points to 208);
| (ptr[1] << 8) bitwise OR transform returned value with '7' shifted 8 bits to the left into:
00000000 00000000 00000111 11010000;
and rest with zeros;
The result is: 00000000 00000000 00000111 11010000, which is in big-endian order, and if i understand correctly flips over into little-endian for storage in dynamic memory in little-endian architectures.
Let's see what's happening on big-end architecture:
    else
    {
        return (*ptr << 24) | (ptr[1] << 16) | (ptr[2] << 8) | ptr[3];
    }

Let's imagine that the number 2000 is written in big-endian order: { 0, 0, 7, 208 }
return (*ptr << 24) returns 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000 (because on big-endian case 'ptr[0]' pointed on zero);
| (ptr[1] << 16) and 'ptr[1]' is zero, so changed nothing: 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000000;
| (ptr[2] << 8) OR changed value into 00000000  00000000  00000111  00000000;
and | ptr[3] finally: 00000000  00000000  00000111  11010000;
big-endian deserialization is clear, but in the case of big-endian order of serialized value. And in my case all serialized values are little-endian.
It turns out that this:
    if (IsLittleEndian)
    {
        return *ptr | (ptr[1] << 8) | (ptr[2] << 16) | (ptr[3] << 24);
    }

will correctly deserialize little-endian value on both endian architectures?
As far as I understand, it flips from little-endian order into big-endian, which will correctly deserialize on big-endian architecture, and somehow works on little endian (apparently because the number is flipped into big-endian order, which is more convenient to work with when performing bitwise operations)?

Serialize and deserialize have to be symmetric.  You can't serialize one way and then deserialize a different way (or have options).  BigEndian and LittleEndian are stored exactly the same in memory.  Both are just an array of bytes.  It is how you use then that is different.  You should be able to use the BigEndian method on LittleEndian data and get the correct results.  When you have bytes 1,2,3,4 in memory and serialize and then deserialize you will get 1,2,3,4.  It doesn't matter that you are really using the bytes as 4:3,2:1

if 'startIndex' is aligned on a 4-byte boundary it casts 'ptr' to integer, which will probably read little-endian value incorrectly on a big-endian architecture. startIndex is a local variable, so its value won't be affeced by endian.

See System.Net.IPAddress. NetworkToHostOrder and HostToNetworkOrder methods. Also see BitConverter.IsLittleEndian.

An expression like *ptr | (ptr[1] << 8) | (ptr[2] << 16) | (ptr[3] << 24) does not depend on the endianness of the CPU it's running on at all (it does depend on the order in which the bytes appear in the stream, which is determined by how you serialized the int to begin with). If that's the correct expression, then it would apply in both cases.

BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian
